# A Beautiful algorithm - Boyer-Moore voting algorithm . Does anyone know similar algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

The Boyer Moore majority vote algorithm employs a beautiful method to highlight the possible majority element in the first pass and then check its validity in the second pass. Does anyone know about a similar class of 2 pass algorithms ? Tried searching but couldn't find . Thanks !! Can you share some of these 2 pass algorithms?

Comment: What is the question? Is there other beautiful algorithms? (1) yes (2) This is subjective

Comment: Can you share at least 1 more algorithm which works on a similar principle?

Comment: till which part you consider is principle? for example, `KMP` is a two-pass algo. have a look, do you think they are similar?

Comment: Another gem is the Graham-Knowlton problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a generalization of the Boyer-Moore algorithm, there is one, proposed by [Karp-Papadimitriou-Shanker](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/498/karp.pdf).

This algorithm is finding candidates for "frequent" elements, where "frequent" is defined to be repeating `1/Θ` times, for some `Θ \in (0,1)`.

The algorithm yields a list of `1/Θ` candidates, some of them could be False-Positives, but it's never missing a candidate.

The algorithm is 1 pass algorithm.

If you can allow 2nd pass on the data, it is easy to verify which of these candidates is indeed "frequent"

Pseudo code for the algorithm (taken from a [course](http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/236620/Spring2013/ho/WCFiles/Lec10-steaming.pdf) I TAed):

```
1. PF = ∅
2. foreach element e∈S {
3.   if PF.hasKey(e) { // increase counter
4.     PF.value(e)++ // of existing elements
5.   }
6.   Else {
7.     PF.insert(e,1) // insert new element
8.     If |PF|== 1/θ { // but if PF is full
9.       Foreach key ∈ PF {
10.        PF.value(k)-- // decrease all counters
11.        if PF.value(k) == 0 { // and remove
12.          PF.remove(k) // elements at 0
13. } } } } }
14. Output PF
```

Comment: Thanks amit . Was looking for this !